I don't see any suggestions from the IDE when trying to import any functions from firebase or @angular/fire libraries (Visual Studio Code)
I want to initialize my Firebase app and use its features in my Angular app. However, after I installed all packages via npm install firebase @angular/fire, I'm not getting any suggestions from the IDE. It behaves as if these packages don't exist, but if I type imports manually, I don't get any errors.
This is my package.json file with all installed dependencies:
{
  "name": "angular-quizz-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/angularfire": "^0.8.38",
    "firebase": "^10.12.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

This is an example, where i should get suggestion from CLI, but CLI doesn't suggest anything:

And this is my user settings in Visual Studio Code:

I've tried different approaches. I've installed types for these packages via npm install @types/firebase @types/angular/fire. Then, I tried to implement initialization in a service instead of calling it in the providers area in the app configuration, but without any result.

Instead of asking for links to information (which is off-topic for stack overflow, and will be closed as such), you should probably edit the question to state which IDE you're using, and tag thee question with that.  The problem might be with the IDE itself and not the packages.  You might also show a specific example of where you are not getting the autocomplete you expect so that someone can reproduce the same situation.

@DougStevenson, i edited my answer, as you suggested. Thank you.

@DougStevenson note that questions focused on asking for where to find official information are on topic. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541

@starball If you look back at the original version 1 of this post, do you think the request for a link was on-topic?  I think it definitely was not, and I would have voted against it.

@DougStevenson I was not saying the part asking for a reference to info was on-topic. nor was I saying it had any good place being in this question. notice that I said "focused" in my previous comment. I merely meant to point out that the statement "asking for links to information is off-topic" is not entirely accurate. I wouldn't like such an underqualified statement to confuse the asker about what is on or off topic. editing that request out of this question post was the right move.

@starball Had I simply edited out the request for link, there would have been essentially no question at all, and therefore still off-topic.  That's also why I asked the OP to rewrite the post into something more specifically answerable by someone with the requisite experience.  I am perfectly happy in this case ultimately trying to help the OP get to a relevant answer at the expense of possibly, slightly misinterpreting the details of off-topic.

in my case the solution was change the moduleResolution strategy in the tscofing.json file.
"moduleResolution": "bundler" to "moduleResolution": "node" // or other


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
